# How to determine whether the 32 or 64 bit version of Windows Server 2008 is installed?

Tags: windows-server-2008

How can one determine if the 32 or 64 bit version of Windwos Server 2008 is installed on a machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right Click on My Computer -> Properties (then look under windows edition)

Answer (score 3):

Start > Run > type: **Winver** and hit enter

Answer (score 2):

Check the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE system variable.  x86 = 32bit, something else = 64bit (mine say AMD64).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "Program Files (x86)" folder on your system drive, you have 64 bit
If not, you have 32 bit